# Redux RTK Query seems not caching requests

Tags: typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm calling the `RTK-Query` lazy hook from two different components with the same parameter.

### github.api.ts

```js
    export const githubApi = createApi({
      reducerPath: "github/api",
      baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: "https://api.github.com/"
      }),
      endpoints: build => ({
        
        getUserRepos: build.query<IRepo[], string>({
          query: (username: string) => ({
            url: `users/${username}/repos`
          })
        })
      }),
      refetchOnFocus: true,
    })

    export const {
      useLazyGetUserReposQuery
    } = githubApi
```

### store.index.ts

```js
    export const store = configureStore({
      reducer: {
        [githubApi.reducerPath]: githubApi.reducer,
      },
      middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => 
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(githubApi.middleware)
    })
```

So in my first component I call it like this:

```js
    const [fetchRepos, { isFetching: areReposLoading, data: repos }] = useLazyGetUserReposQuery()

    fetchRepos(`sss`)
```

Then I change location (unload first component and switch to another component)
And in the second (another) component I call the same hook with the same parameter (string `sss`) but instead giving me the cached value the `RTK-Query` fires another request and gives me the same data back, but not from cache..
[image]

Here's the link to the entire src code:
[github.rtk.query.app](https://github.com/slimbde/react-2022)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `useLazyQuery`, you have to indicate to the trigger function that you actually want to use the cache value and not start a new request to the server:

```
    fetchRepos(`sss`, true)
```

Quoting the docs: [useLazyQuery](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery)

> Note
>
> When the trigger function returned from a LazyQuery is called, it always initiates a new request to the server even if there is cached data. Set preferCacheValue(the second argument to the function) as true if you want it to immediately return a cached value if one exists.

Comment: YES! Thank you so much. That's what I was waiting for! So sad I didn't get this feature from the docs.

Comment: It *is* in the docs, but you have to scroll a little - I edited a link to the docs and the quote into my answer above.

Comment: Yes, @phry, I've already seen that bold font describing the second argument behaviour (in `Using RTK Query - Queries` documentation section). I have no idea why I didn't notice it before. Thank you very much. You guys made a really amazing tool that will replace lots of code in my projects.